# MSB4019 error when building MVC 5 app after cloning from DevOps on Mac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I just got a new mac and installed the latest VS 2022. I cloned a DevOps repository with a ASP.Net Mvc 5 app. The app always ran fine on my Windows machine, but when I try to build it on my Mac, I am getting this error

> Error MSB4019: The imported project "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v17.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v17.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk. (MSB4019)

It seems like it is a common issue, but I was not able to find any solutions that worked for me. I can confirm that the `v17.0` folder is actually missing the entire `WebApplications` folder.

What I have tried:

1. Reinstall VS multiple times and reclone repository each time
2. Go to `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/` and copy `WebApplications` folder from v16.0 to v17.0. Produces many more errors on `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` file.

My question: Why am I missing the `WebApplications` folder and what can I do to get it?

Comment: Have you installed Visual Studio's web templates?

Comment: @SNBS Yes I have. I installed everything available

Comment: I tried following this article and created the V17 folder, worked


https://medium.com/asecuritysite-when-bob-met-alice/going-native-with-coding-4d710cbc951c

Comment: @Thilo I did exactly that, except when I saw all the errors, I did not update that package. Great article, I will try that.

Comment: @Thilo if you make an answer I will except it for other people with this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Copy from medium:
https://medium.com/asecuritysite-when-bob-met-alice/going-native-with-coding-4d710cbc951c

```
% cd /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v16.0/WebApplications
% sudo mkdir ../../v17.0/WebApplications
% sudo cp Microsoft.WebApplication.targets ../../v17.0/WebApplications
```

done!